# Get the index of an <article> relevant to document, not parent

Tags: jquery, html

What I am trying to do here is to add a class to each article element containing its number relevant to the document. The following code add the number relevant to element first parent. Any suggestions??

```
<main class="container">    
    <article class="tile">  //returns t1
        <h1>A1</h1>
    </article>    
    <article class="tile">  //returns t2
        <h1>A2</h1>
    </article>        
</main>
<main class="container">        
    <article class="tile">  //returns t3
        <h1>B1</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">  //returns t4
        <h1>B2</h1>
    </article>
    <article class="tile">  //returns t5
        <h1>B3</h1>
    </article>    
</main>
```

```js
$('article.tile').each(function () { 
     var tNumber = $(this).index() + 1 ;
     $(this).addClass('t'+tNumber)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to provide a selector to `index()`, otherwise it will take in to account the index of the current element within it's current parent element. Try this:

```
$('article.tile').each(function () { 
     var tNumber = $(this).index('article.tile') + 1;
     $(this).addClass('t' + tNumber)
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kmkhb4Lz/)

Alternatively you can remove the `each()` call and use the `index` parameter passed directly to `addClass` when you use a handler function to derive the class name to be added:

```
$('article.tile').addClass(function(i) {
    return 't' + (i + 1)
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kmkhb4Lz/1/)